# Offset a symbol without changing layout

Tags: positioning

I'm using a certain symbol that I would like to shift down without effecting it's layout(change the surrounding markup's positions):

a test case is:

```
$\begin{array}{ccc}
   a & b & c\\
   a & b & e\\
\end{array}$
```

and I want to move c down just right on top of e so the bottom of c touches, or even overlap, the top of e without effecting the layout at all(except for c). The two matrices should look identical except for how c changes.

(the answer should be relatively generic since the above is just a test case)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `\smash` and `\raisebox`:

[image]

### Notes:

- The `\hlines` were added so as to be able to compare the before and after.
- The `\raisebox` is used to lower the desired character, and the `\smash` is used to ensure that the remainder of the environment is not affected by it.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\begin{array}{ccc}\hline
   a & b & c\\
   a & b & e\\\hline
\end{array}$
$\begin{array}{ccc}\hline
   a & b & \smash{\raisebox{-1.75ex}{c}}\\
   a & b & e\\\hline
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

A nested `array` puts a `c` over `e`. This avoids that `c` and `e` are on different lines in the outer `array` and the positioning becomes independent from the contents of the other cells that might increase the distances of the rows. The inner `array` needs `b` to put the `e` on the baseline, see Peter Grill's comment.

Another trick is using `\arraystretch` with meaning `0`. Then the struts are reset with nullified heights and depths that are inserted by environment `array`.

As requested in the question, `\smash` nullifies the height (and depth) of `c`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\begin{array}{ccc}
   a & b & \\
   a & b &
  \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{0}%
  \begin{array}[b]{@{}c@{}}\smash{c}\\e\end{array}\\
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: The bottom of the `e` is not quite at the baseline.  Using `\begin{array}[b]` for the inner `array` appears to fix it.